# Need an elixir function that sends a message to a phone number

Tags: database-design, elixir, elixir-poison

I am new to programming in general and currently learning Elixir.

How do I write a function that sends message to a phone number? I would love to see the syntax. I'm using the Phoenix framework.

I saw this, but its not exactly what I want:

```
def tell(receiver, message) do
  IO.puts "[#{inspect self}] Sending #{message} to #{inspect receiver}"
  send receiver, {:ok, self, message}
end
```

Comment: @JustMichael the functions making you rich are usually written in Java since ML AI  DL Bitcoin is better to mine in Kafka.

Comment: @mudasobwa Truly good point, thank you.

Comment: I saw the `make_me_rich` function at one point but it was coded in Javascript so I recoiled in horror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about SMS, the easiest way to do that is to first subscribe to a messaging provider like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms) and get yourself an API key. Then you can utilize their REST API for sending text messages.

Comment: thanks Lee. my confusion now is that twilio don't support elixir so how do i go about it

Comment: They have RESTful API which means you can call them using HTTPoison or HTTPotion thru HTTP.